# Ошибка при перегрузке функции TS

Tags: typescript, function-overloading

Кто-нибудь может мне объяснить, почему это работает:

```
interface M {
    (a: number): any;
    (a: number[]): any;
}

const foo: M = (a) => {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        return a.map((num) => num > 0 || num === 0 ? num : num * -1)
    } else {
        return a > 0 || a === 0 ? a : a * -1;
    }
}
```

а если я поменяю интерфейс на

```
interface M {
    (a: number): number;
    (a: number[]): number[];
}
```

что кажется вполне логичным, то получаю следующую ошибку

```
Type '(a: number | number[]) => number | number[]' is not assignable to type 'M'.   
Type 'number | number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.     
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Я не понимаю...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тип `any` совместим с **любым** другим типом. Поэтому работает первый вариант.

Во втором варианте указывается конкретный тип возвращаемого значения. Проблема заключается в том, что реализация должна удовлетворять сразу всем перегрузкам в данном случае.

То есть, одновременно должен возвращаться и `number` и `number[]`. Что в typescript возможно только при использовании `any` в качестве возвращаемого значения:

```
interface M {
    (a: number): number;
    (a: number[]): number[];
}

const foo: M = (a): any => {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        return a.map((num) => num > 0 || num === 0 ? num : num * -1)
    } else {
        return a > 0 || a === 0 ? a : a * -1;
    }
}
```

[**playground**](http://%5BPlayground%20Link%5D(https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLLIN4Chm%20QCjgC5kQBXAWwCNoBKE866Abhz0IcpqgG0BdeqS7R%20rAL5YsCAPYgAzmGQxp0kugC8BOPTggAnsnUA%20TG1zAYBAIJQocPQDpgcm3b2FatU3h-IoEMDIoEGQ4Bwo4AAd8fEYvYyEKZBMABmQAH3TEw3VNNIB%20bM4kgCpkAFoARlozZDFkCAAbORRsXzx-QODQ5OQ0zJ7cvORCuGQSMbKq1h8JMSA))

Comment: Значит мы должны возвращать одинаковый тип, да и одинаковые параметры в перегрузке должны быть однотипны...я думал тут больше простора

Comment: @DenisLopatin, нет, не должны. в примере твой же interface используется.